# Fastest possible key->value disc store with mutiple values

Tags: java, persistence, nosql, berkeley-db

I'm looking for a efficient way to store many key->value pairs
on disc for persistence, preferably with some caching.

The features needed are to either add to the value (concatenate)
for a given key or to let the model be key -> list of values,
both options are fine. The value-part is typically a binary document.

I will not have too much use of clustering, redundancy etc in this scenario.

Language-wise we're using java and we are experienced in classic databases (Oracle, MySQL and more).

I see a couple of obvious scenarios and would like advice on what
is fastest in terms of stores (and retrievals) per second:

1) Store the data in classic db-tables by standard inserts.

2) Do it yourself using a file system tree to spread to many files,
one or several per key.

3) Use some well known tuple-storage. Some obvious candidates are:
   3a) Berkeley db java edition
   3b) Modern NoSQL-solutions like cassandra and similar

Personally I like the Berkely DB JE for my task.

To summarize my questions:

- Does Berkely seem like a sensible choice given the above?
- What kind of speed can I expect for some operations, like
  updates (insert, addition of new value for a key) and 
  retrievals given key?

Answer (score 4):

You could also give a try to [Chronicle Map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map) or [JetBrains Xodus](https://github.com/jetbrains/xodus) which are both Java embeddable key-value stores [much faster than Berkeley DB JE](http://jetbrains.github.io/xodus/#benchmarks) (if you are really looking for speed). Chronicle Map provides an easy-to-use `java.util.Map` interface.

Answer (score 2):

BerkeleyDB sounds sensible. Cassandra would also be sensible but perhaps is overkill if you don't need redundancy, clustering etc.

That said, a single Cassandra node can handle 20k writes per second (provided that you use multiple clients to exploit the high concurrency within Cassandra) on relatively modest hardware.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I'm using [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) with completely satisfactory performance; I've never tried Berkeley DB.

Answer (score 1):

Berkeley DB JE should work just fine for the use case that you describe. Performance will vary, largely depending on how many I/Os are required per operation (and the corollary -- how big is the available cache) and on the durability constraints that you define for your write transactions (ie. does a commit transaction have to write all the way to the disk or not)?

Generally speaking, we typically see 50-100K reads per second and 5-12K writes per second on commodity hardware with BDB JE. Obviously, YMMV.

Performance tuning and throughput questions about BDB JE are best asked on the [Berkeley DB JE forum](http://bit.ly/e1AYFi), where there is an active community of BDB JE application developers on hand to help out. There are several useful performance tuning recommendations in the [BDB JE FAQ](http://bit.ly/gzchuD) which may also come in handy.

Best of luck with your implementation. Please let us know if we can help.

Regards,

Dave -- Product Manager for Berkeley DB